# using memory barriers correctly

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, barrier

I am trying to understand how do memory barriers work and how useful they are. I am aware of the fact that they are not worth complicating my code in most cases, but it's still an interesting topic. Trying to build a mental model around it but I don't quite succeed *yet*.

I have probably succeeded in understanding release and acquire enough to be able to correctly, or at least more correctly, use or understand volatile fields. My problem is usage of full memory barriers. For example, here is a link to some description:
https://afana.me/archive/2015/07/10/memory-barriers-in-dot-net.aspx/

In the section called "cache coherency" there is an example where cpu2 may not see the store to `y` even when the memory barrier is executed after memory barrier of cpu1. I get what happens here, most likely. But the fixed example contains two memory barriers, an additional one is after both stores in cpu1 and before both loads in cpu2. My specific question here is: isn't it enough to add a barrier before both loads and after both stores, but removing this one in between? why/why not? I will probably have more related question as this is not easy to get right even theoretically...

Comment: the two processors are independent; there is no reliable point in time that is "before both loads and after both stores" - as those things aren't linked in any way; the threads could be at any offset from each other, and they don't have to progress equally - one thread could be blocked on memory access or just a thread interrupt - while the other carries on

Comment: this description assumes that the barrier executes after a respective barrier on the cpu doing stores. I am aware of the fact that it isn't quite possible to predict that, but simplifications are often useful (provided you remember about them) to understand things. for example you could assume an example order of execution, and in this case the author has assumed that barrier in second cpu has for some reason executed after the barrier in the first one. And I maintain the same assumption for this specific question.

Comment: I do not believe that it is possible to simplify memory barrier semantics to make it easier to understand; nor do I believe that it is even remotely possible to assume an example order of execution; I mean, sure that gives you an example, but that **does not** tell you anything about every way the CPU could behave. The point of memory barriers is about GUARANTEES of what happens, not assumptions and simplifications. This is an inherently deeply complex topic, and 99% of the time, people who say "I think I understand this": actually don't. Including me, for sure.

Comment: but because I don't necessarily realize what these guarantees mean in some cases, I am asking about some specific very hard to observe stuff. And in this specific case I am also trying to validate what I read in the article. Because my understanding was that I don't need two memory barriers and that the one after both stores and one before both loads is enough, especially that I don't care about their order. relative to each other, I just want to guarantee I get both values or none. as in either both are not modified or both are modified.

Comment: The abstraction level I mean relates to memory ordering. It may be interesting to know what the processor actually does or may do for explanatory purposes, but I don't necessarily have to understand this part, as it is also cpu specific. Although if it would be required to explain something, I could assume a cpu with weak memory ordering. I believe I've heard arm has a weaker memory order than x86.